# jQuery Selection does not work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In my HTML document I have got a table with an empty table body, which gets automatically filled by jQuery when the document is completely loaded. The table body is generated by a PHP script, jQuery gets the content with a simple GET request.

Here is my PHP code...

```
<?php

// ...
// ...
// Just take a look at the following two lines,
// the other code is not important in this case.
while ($tableDataRow = $tableData->fetch_assoc())
    echo '<tr><td>'. $tableDataRow['id']. '</td><td>'. $tableDataRow['name']. '</td><td><a href="#" class="delete-row" data-id="'. $tableDataRow['id']. '">Delete</a></td></tr>';

?>
```

The output could be...

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>Nadine</td><td><a href="#" class="delete-row" data-id="1">Delete</a></td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Nicole</td><td><a href="#" class="delete-row" data-id="2">Delete</a></td></tr>
```

Everything works perfect, the only problem is that jQuery does not react if any click event occurs. My jQuery code looks like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete-row").click(function(event) { // "a[class=delete-row]" does not work, too. But "*" works for every element, even for the links?!
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("You clicked on that link!")
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to change like this: `$('body').on('click', '.delete-row', function(event) { ... });`

Comment: wrong use of keyword function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.click()` makes use of jQuery's [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method, which basically takes a snapshot of the DOM. In this case, that snapshot would be generated on document ready.

As your PHP code is dynamically added to the page, this will not be included in the document ready DOM snapshot. For this reason, jQuery has an [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method which can be used instead:

```
$("table").on('click', '.delete-row', function() { ... });
```

This is known as event delegation.

Answer (score 2):

Use delegation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mytable").on("click",".delete-row",function(event) { // "a[class=delete-row]" does not work, too. But "*" works for every element, even for the links?!
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("You clicked on that link!")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Events are bind at the generation of the page but your table is attached after so you should use something like "on" or whatever is the latest event bind method of jQuery instead of "click"

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the issue is due to your elements being added to the DOM after the page has loaded (IE. via ajax request), this would mean that `$(".delete-row").click(function(event) {});` would fail as the element was missing when registered the way round this is to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('.parentElement').on('click','.delete-row',function() {
   event.preventDefault();
  alert("You clicked on that link!");
});
```

`.parentElement` would be an element that is parent of your ajax added html but not dynamically added itself.